# How to handle database connection exceptions in a lambda function with NestJs?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, aws-lambda, error-handling, nestjs

I'm working in a lambda function with NestJs framework and the `@nestjs/mongoose` package as database connection provider. My problem is that I want to catch the exceptions that happen when the module loads.

I tried to use an [Exception Filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) in my `main.ts` as a global filter but it can't handled them 'cause NestJs loads the modules first and then the configurations from the `main.ts`, so maybe this can't be the solution.

By the way, when the module that make the mongodb connection fails the app logs the exception with the built-in NestJs logger but the app still running, so the lambda function timeout is over and the response that I get is a (504) `GATEWAY_TIMEOUT` status.

Database Module:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [MongoConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (config: MongoConfigService) => ({
                uri: config.URI,
                // ... more config stuff here ...
            }),
            inject: [MongoConfigService],
        }),
    ],
    providers: [],
})
export class MongoDatabaseProviderModule {}
```

main.ts:

```
let server: Handler;

async function bootstrap(): Promise<Handler> {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(ApiModule, { bufferLogs: true });

    app.useLogger(app.get(Logger));
    app.flushLogs();

    const httpAdapter = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);

    app.useGlobalFilters(
        new AllExceptionsFilter(httpAdapter),
    );

    await app.init();

    const appConfig: AppConfigService = app.get(AppConfigService);
    app.setGlobalPrefix(appConfig.STAGE);

    const expressApp = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
    return serverlessExpress({ app: expressApp });
}

export const handler: Handler = async (event: unknown, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
    server = server ?? (await bootstrap());
    return server(event, context, callback);
};
```

Exception Filter:

```
@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}

    catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
        const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;

        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();

        const httpStatus =
            exception instanceof HttpException
                ? exception.getStatus()
                : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

        const responseBody = {
            statusCode: httpStatus,
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            path: httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(ctx.getRequest()),
        };

        httpAdapter.reply(ctx.getResponse(), responseBody, httpStatus);
    }
}
```

What I expect is to know how to handle the exceptions from a module when its loading. In order to give a quick response when an error occurs.